# Automated Way to Find Android Activity

Tags: android, aapt

I have built a script, a part of an automation tool I've developed, that needs to open an apk and find the activity so it can launch it. To do so I have used:

```
aapt dump badging x.apk
```

Which 'should' dump out the activity(s) of the application. Some times it has, others it has not. Is there a more reliable method to dump the activities of an application so my script can pick up the activity and launch the package via adb instrumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$ aapt dump --values xmltree <name>.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

and then you have to parse the output to find the Activities.

Remember that you also have to find the **instrumentation** in the manifest if your intention is to run instrumentation automatically.